# Tuning Wildfly for high concurrency

Tags: linux, sockets, tcp, linux-kernel, wildfly

We are experiencing high load on an application which is running on `Wildfly 9.0.2` application server port `8080`.

> We see `TCP: request_sock_TCP: Possible SYN flooding on port 8080` in linux system log message quite a few times after which all the requests on this port `timed-out`.

**What I found online**

After going through some blogs and other online resources it came out that to cope up with the incoming traffic tuning below parameters at kernel and application level

- the kernel's socket backlog limit
- the application's socket listen backlog

Changing one and not the other will not have any effect. It means tuning at both kernel and application level is required.

**Kernel-**

The `kernel's socket backlog limit` is controlled by the `net.core.somaxconn` kernel tunable. It may also be necessary to change the limit of currently-handshaking `(SYN-RECV and waiting for ACK)` connections on a socket with the `net.ipv4.tcp_max_syn_backlog` kernel tunable.

I have changed these parameters to sufficient values but I couldn't find any corresponding setting at `Wildfly` end for this. Instinctively I have changed below Wildfly setting but not sure if it pairs up well with the above kernel settings

**Wildfly - standalone.xml**

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:io:1.1">
    <worker name="default" io-threads="128" task-keepalive="120" task-max-threads="2048"/>
    <buffer-pool name="default"/>
</subsystem>
```

**My Question:**

- Is there anything I am missing?
- how to change Wildfly's socket listen backlog

Comment: So the final question is "how to change Wildfly's socket listen backlog"?

Comment: @red0ct Yes....